# What is the default colour of the x, y and z axis in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

This may seem like an overly simple question. What is the default colour of the x, y and z axis in Matlab? I have searched the internet and can't seem to find an answer. Bellow is a sample graph. As I know the data, I think the blue line represents z axis, red represents y axis and yellow represents the x axis. However, I am not sure and would like someone to confirm this,

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab will colour plots consecutively from the same palette in the order in which you call the ´plot´ commands, so in all your examples the blue line is the first one you plotted and so on. The `colororder` is static but can be changed. See [this](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-are-plot-lines-different-colors.html) page for the order and how to change it.

As far as 'x, y and z' goes are you referring to the meanings you have ascribed to the data? Because matlab doesn't infer anything like that - if your variables are called `x` or `y` or whatever it will ignore that and plot them in the order you called the plot commands.

Comment: You can also use legend() after calling plot to provide a legend instead of trying to figure out which line represents which data set by color.